# Image Recognition using OpenCv and android

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-studio, image-processing

I want to work on making an android app by integrating OpenCV with android Studio. I have a set of 2D hardcopy card images that i want to save as templates with in the app. Then, using the app, when i place my camera on any of the cards, the app should search the directory which contain the templates and look for match and provide feedback if a match is found. If anyone can guide on how to achieve this, it will be highly appreciated.

Also, if not OpenCV, then which SDK or tool should be preferred ?

Comment: Please see [ask]. The question is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a general one, so the answer will be general as well, and will make assumptions about what you'd like to accomplish with your application.

Android Studio with OpenCV is probably a reasonable stack to use.

Presuming the library has more than a trivial number of images, you'll probably want to extract matching information for each image in your library in an offline process (on your code-development machine).  So for instance, you would configure your development machine with a SQLite database driver and OpenCV, construct a program that extracts feature points and saves those to your a SQLite database.  That file can then be loaded into the Android APK assets, and it would be ready upon the application's first use.  The application would take frames from the camera and compare those with each item in the database, looking for matches.